# Azure AD b2c Account lockout threshold

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to set "Account lockout threshold" and "Lockout duration" for a sign in policy in azure ad b2c?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe you can configure these lockout settings, using either the Azure Portal or the Azure AD Graph API.

(I hope, in future, Azure AD B2C allows customization of [the smart lockout values that are supported by Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-password-smart-lockout#manage-azure-ad-smart-lockout-values).)